# Qt Installer, overwrite previous version

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I am using the latest Qt Installer version 2.0.3
I have created an installer for my app, but when I try to install it I get the following error message: "The folder you selected already exists and contains an installation. Chose different target for installation"

How can I indicate Qt Installer to overwrite the old version? is this officially supported?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `MaintenanceTool`. It's in the root folder of the Qt installation, which on Linux is

```bash
bash -c "$HOME/Qt/MaintenanceTool"
```

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: thank you. Why they don't put this in the start menu is beyond me

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code below. You will always have the same id for your application and you will be able to overwrite your application.

```
function Controller()
{
    installer.setValue("ProductUUID", "YourApplicationName");

    var previous = installer.value("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\YourApplicationName\\InstallLocation");
    if(previous !== "")
    {
        installer.setValue("TargetDir", previous);
        installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.TargetDirectory, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not officially supported for some reason. To get it to work, you have to do some hacking. I have listed the steps that work for me in the answer for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455360/workaround-for-qt-installer-framework-not-overwriting-existing-installation/46614107#46614107).