# Create .msi installer with Qt installer framework

Tags: c++, qt, windows-installer, qt-installer

I've been looking into the Qt installer framework but when you create a setup using this tool it is a regular setup though I was wondering whether it would be possible to create an msi setup to be able to install a Qt program network wide.

I've looked at the installer framework docs but was unable to find anything about this so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt installer framework doesn't provide creating of MSI installer. For MSIs you should use WiX for example.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems dull that they don't support this out of the box since Qt is such a business oriented framework, but oh well

Comment: @LiamMartens The Qt Installer Framework is not really a part of Qt and my personal thinking about it is that its main purpose is to be used to create Qt installers by The Qt Company, not to be a complete installer solution like Wix or InnoSetup. And therefore, it lacks many basic features, like being able to update an existing installation: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-401

Comment: @BenjaminT Updating is possible but [a bit tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455360/workaround-for-qt-installer-framework-not-overwriting-existing-installation/46614107#46614107) yes

Answer (score 3):

You have got a proper answer, maybe I'll add some further links for you. Before I do that I can verify that WiX can be used to make MSI installers for any type of Windows application.

There are also a few other tools available to make MSI files that you might want to look at depending on your needs - both open source (free) and commercial. Though WiX is very flexible and great when you have it set up, commercial tools can help you get an MSI created much quicker. Have a read below of the different tools and their pros and cons.

---

**Below are a few links for you** - I am a "linking monster" :-). If you pardon what looks like shameless self-promotion, it is really a guess as to what you could find useful to get your MSI file created:

- **[What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)** (various MSI tools with description of pros and cons)
- [Windows Installer and the creation of WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060281/windows-installer-and-the-creation-of-wix/12101548#12101548) (a little unofficial story of WiX's creation)
- [WiX "quick start" suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (getting started with WiX - not my favorite answer - it is a bit messy - but somehow it seems to be helpful for people)
- [How do I avoid common design flaws in my WiX / MSI deployment solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840086/how-do-i-avoid-common-design-flaws-in-my-wix-msi-deployment-solution/45840087#45840087) (messy, but may be worth a skim to avoid some problems)

---

And a few more peripheral links thrown in:

- [Syntax for guids in WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732761/syntax-for-guids-in-wix/24769965#24769965) (simplifying WiX source files)
- [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) (tools you can use to inspect the compiled MSI files - and some tips for comparing different versions and decompiling MSI files)
- [Change my component GUID in wix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix/1422121#1422121) (understanding the critical component GUID concept in Windows Installer / MSI)