# Qt Installer Framework. How to enable overwrite installation

Tags: qt, qt-installer

The last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455360/workaround-for-qt-installer-framework-not-overwriting-existing-installation) about overwriting existing installation was 3 years ago on QtIFW 2, 3, so I hope this won't count as duplicate posting.

I have a Mac installer setup that have 2 components: a standalone app, a VST3 audio plugin.
The standalone is located in @TargetDir@ (which is `/Applications/MyApp`) and the plugin is located in (`/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/MyApp.vst3`)

To install the vst3 in Library I use CopyDirectory on `createOperationsForArchive` in the `installscript.qs`

```
// File at installer/packages/com.packagename/meta/installscript.qs
function Component()
{
}

Component.prototype.createOperationsForArchive = function(archive)
{
    // Extract data to pluto folder in Orpheus
    component.addOperation("Extract", archive, "@TargetDir@/myplugin/");

    // Copy plugin to Library
    component.addElevatedOperation(
        "CopyDirectory",
        "@TargetDir@/myplugin/Myplugin.component",
        "/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/"
    );
}
```

I would like the installer to be able to overwrite the app if already exists. My thinking was to add a remove script before `CopyDirectory`. So I added below codes to before CopyDirectory operation:

```
component.addElevatedOperation(
    "Execute", "bash",
    "rm", "-rf", "/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/Pluto.component"
);
```

But I got permission error exit code 126.

I also tried `Rmdir` operation, but got `Cannon remove directory` error with `Undefined error:0` error.

Another option seems to be to invoke `maintenance tool` but I don't know how to add a specific path to delete for the plugin as the maintenance tool will only delete what is in `TargetDir`.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by checking the installation log, when I accidentally add the `UNDOEXECUTE` argument to `CopyDirectory`

`Invalid argument in CopyDirectory: Third argument needs to be forceOverwrite, if specified. Retry|Ignore|Cancel`

So the solution to overwrite using `CopyDirectory` is simply:

```
component.addElevatedOperation(
    "CopyDirectory",
    "@TargetDir@/pluto/Myplugin.component",
    "/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/",
    "forceOverwrite")
```

This is quite tricky because `forceOverwite` is no where to be found in the Documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/operations.html